# How to do a conditional FormControl

Tags: angular

I'm creating a FormGroup that is used by two components, but for of them I need to remove a property that it does not need, my code is similar to:

```
const myForm = new FormGroup({
  'name': new FormControl('', [CustomValidators.required()]),
  'email': new FormControl('', [CustomValidators.required()])
  ])
})
```

I need to remove the email for the FormGroup when a variable X is false.

Someone has any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
let x = false;
let formGroup = {
    'name': new FormControl('', [CustomValidators.required()])
}

if (x) {
    formGroup['email'] = new FormControl('', [CustomValidators.required()]);
}

const myForm = new FormGroup(formGroup);
```

Answer (score 7):

To conditionally handle FormControl based on variables, use methods addControl and removeControl as a proper solution

```
const myForm = new FormGroup({
  'name': new FormControl('', [CustomValidators.required()]),
});

if(x) {
  myForm.addControl('email', new FormControl('', Validators.required);
}
```

Values and other attributes like disabled can also be used together and also an array of validators can be passed

```
if(x) {
  myForm.addControl('email', new FormControl({value: 'test@gmail.com', disabled: false}, [Validators.requried, CustomValidators.required]);
}
```